# How to get wordnet domains hierarchy in python?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I have a keyword like '**SPORTS**'. I need to have all its first childs, i.e next hierarchical level. So I should get something like [cricket,football,tennis,hockey].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding to your question your actual code and what concrete problem you have, to make it easier to the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It should work something like this(assuming you are using nltk):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
sport = wn.synset('sport.n.01')
sport.hyponyms()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for recursive hyponyms, try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
sport = wn.synset('sport.n.01')
typesOfSport = list(set([w for s in sport.closure(lambda s:s.hyponyms()) for w in s.lemma_names]))
```